# Apache Solr view on Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, solr

I got and issue with apache solr. I need to make the search display results regardless of the current language of the website. At the moment I am trying with apache solr view, but I still can't get it to work properly. It still gives me an "ss_language" default value like 'und' and 'en'. All I need it to do is to search in all languages. 
Ps. I am kinda new on Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

This module might help you for that

https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multilingual

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I have the module enabled already, but i can't find any setting that might help me.